# SQL SERVER 2005 USE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

What is the best way to handle if USE {invalid_database_name} is failed? I would like to ignore the rest of the statements in such cases. This is so as to avoid accidentally run the script on wrong database.
Thanks for your suggestion !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a Database exists :

```
IF DB_ID("<your database>" IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    // Your code here
END
```

or if it is a stored procedure :

```
IF DB_ID("<your database>" IS NULL
BEGIN
    RETURN
END
```

That's better that searching in sysobjects.

Answer (score 3):

Run the script in [SQLCMD mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx) in SSMS and use [`:on error exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx). If you run the script form an app, use a library that is sqlcmd mode compatible, like [dbutilsqlcmd](http://code.google.com/p/dbutilsqlcmd/).

*Edit*

What the many responses recommending various forms of `IF` and `RETURN` and `sp_executesql` are missing is that they only solve the problem of not executing a **batch** (the sequence delimited by `GO`). This helps little when talking about a **script**. The batch that verifies the DB existence will skip the statements, fine, but the very next batch in the script will continue and do whatever it does (eg. create tables) in the current database, not in the desired database. Adding a check at the begging of each batch is tedious and error prone, placing the entire script in a single batch is often not possible. Best solution is to simple do an `USE <inexisting name>` and rely on the `:on error exit` to interrupt the script execution at first error.

Answer (score 2):

you need to check if the Database with the name exists by

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
           WHERE ('[' + name + ']' = @dbname OR name = @dbname))
BEGIN
     --Your Code here
     [USE myDatabase]
END
```

Comment: USE @dbname will not work. USE does not accept a variable. You'd have to do something like the following.  exec ('USE ' + @dbname )

Answer (score 0):

Try Use This

```
begin try
declare @use nvarchar(50)
set @use= 'use MyDB'
exec sp_executesql @use

select top 1 * from MyDB.dbo.TableA


end try
begin catch
print @@ERROR   --Error Number of Database not Found
print Error_message() -- Proper Message
end catch
```